# Which PIC compiler was used to compile this code?

Tags: c, pic

The PIC is a **16F630**

```
#FUSES NOWDT, INTRC_IO, PROTECT, NOBROWNOUT, MCLR, CPD, NOPUT
#use delay(clock=4000000)
#use fast_io(A)
```

later, in a function:

```
    #asm   nop nop nop nop nop   #endasm
```

Which C compiler could have been used to compile this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the [CCS PIC MCU C compiler](http://www.ccsinfo.com/content.php?page=syntax-functions).

As you can see at the link its pre-processor supports `#FUSES`, `#USE`, `#ASM` and `#ENDASM`.

Answer (score 0):

I think mikroC PRO for PIC can compile that,
Regards,
Luka

Answer (score 0):

It seems like CCS compiler. see some complier tags in CCS

```
#FUSES NOWDT                    //No Watch Dog Timer
#FUSES INTRC_IO
```